How to add the basis state $\vert 0 \rangle$ to an arbitrary uniform superposition state?
There is an unknown uniform superposition state $$\vert \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} (\vert k_1 \rangle + \vert k_2 \rangle + \cdots + \vert k_N \rangle),$$ where $$k_1 \neq k_2 \neq \cdots k_p \neq 0,$$
$k_i$ is unknown but $N$ is known. How to construct an efficient circuit satisfying
$$U\vert \psi \rangle  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}} (\vert 0 \rangle+\vert k_1 \rangle + \vert k_2 \rangle + \cdots + \vert k_N \rangle)?$$

This operation isn't possible to construct. It violates unitarity. For example, it would map the orthogonal states $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ to the non-orthogonal states $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |2\rangle)$. But unitary operations always preserve orthogonality.
